# How to call a returning value function in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to andorid programming I've just stucked into a problem to call returning value function inside AsyncTask's `doInBackground()`
Simple question is How to wait for AsyncTask to complete and then execute return statement without freezing UI, i've also studied `onPostExecute()` but it doesn't solve problem.
following is sample code

```
public String hello()  {
   String result = null;
   //calling asynctaske execute method
   retrun result;
}
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of AsyncTask being asynchronous. You will not return anything as the task can end at a later time.
Have your hello method start the AsyncTask, and the onPostExecute() run something on the UI thread, modifying whatever you need to show the output. Therefore hello() cannot have a return type.

Comment: onPostexecute() method will get called once the asychtask is finished.So you could assing the value within onPostExecute().

Comment: ya i've assigned but how do tell next statement to execute except     while(result == null) {  } because it freezez the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For myself i do this with a callback Function, that i invoke after onPostExecute.

```
public AsyncUnzip(Activity ctx, Observer callback) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dia = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    dia.setTitle("Bitte warten");
    dia.setMessage("Geodatenpaket wird entpackt...");
    dia.setCancelable(false);
    dia.show();
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute( Boolean result ) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    dia.dismiss();
    callback.update(null, returnFolder);
    System.out.println("Unzipped to: " + returnFolder.getName() );
}
```

---

In that case your call of Async Task would look like that:

```
AsyncUnzip unzipThread = new AsyncUnzip(ImportActivity.this, new Observer() {
    @Override
    public void update( Observable observable, Object data ) {//your code invoked after Async Task
} });
unzipThread.execute(selectedFile); //Start Unzip in external Thread.
```

---

Note: This is a quick and diry solution with a annonymous Observer implementation and without an observable.

Comment: In your solution, you've directly done the work after asyncTask but i have to return a string to calling function and then it will do its work on it

Comment: i dont understand, Code after .execute(..) is executed as the Asynconus thread is started and the code in the method update(..){} is executed after the Async Task has finisehd

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Interface and return value from `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask or you can register a BroadcastReceiver and fire in from `onPostExecute()` method of AsyncTask. I had created a [demo](https://github.com/lalit3686/AsyncTaskReturnValue) using Interface and BroadcastReceiver you can download and check it.