# How to test asynchronous HTTP request and response Android

Tags: android, junit, android-asynctask, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-testing

I have a user registration form with a "Submit" button. Basically, when "Submit" button is pressed, a AsyncTask is spawn. This AsysncTask sends a HTTP request (using Apache `HttpClient`) consisting of the inputs in the form e.g. IC No. is sent to a server. Some response is expected.

RegistrationActivity has the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendActivation(v);
            }
        });
...
}
public void sendActivation(View v) {
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputIcNo);
        if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
            showErrorMessage("IC No. cannot be blank!");
            return;
        }

        mProcess = new AsyncProcess(this, this.getApplicationContext());
        mProcess.initActivation(text.getText().toString(), null);
        mProcess.execute();
    }
```

RegistrationActivityUnitTest:

```
ImageButton submitBtn = (ImageButton) this.activity.findViewById(R.id.BtnSubmit);
        assertNotNull(submitBtn);
        submitBtn.performClick();
// I don't know what to do from here!
```

How do I test the sending HTTP request and receiving response using AsyncTask?

I'm perfectly happy to break it down and test 1 small thing at a time
e.g. first, does the AsyncTask run when the button is pressed?
Second, does the AsyncTask send a HTTP request?
Next, does the app receive a response for the same HTTP request?
etc.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, your question is where do you can check the response of the asynchronous request. Maybe take a look at [thispost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014322/how-to-call-a-returning-value-function-in-asynctask/18014623#18014623). I dont know if there is a better soloution, but i did that by passing an Observer object, as callback function. In your case the implementation of "update" coud check the respose of the request.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasH, my question is a about Android JUnit testing, now about how to work with AsyncTask

Comment: Oh ok, maybe take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html, but i dont know if you can derive the http requests that where send