# How to hide loader when all async calls are done

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I wanted to know what is the best approach for showing a spinner/loader while I am making a few async calls.

I want to hide it when they are all done.
Should I use a counter of the expected calls to be made?
Is there any other approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this :) [AsyncTask: HowTo][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014322/how-to-call-a-returning-value-function-in-asynctask/18014623#18014623

Comment: Instead of using a counter I think the best way to do that is using a boradcast call when your AsyncTask is done. Then you can have a manager to hold boolean fields